# Add a line chart beneath an existing pie chart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, pie-chart, linechart

When I click on a section of my piechart, I would like to see under first chart another chart (line chart). Now I generated another panel chart, but I lost first panel, because the second chart paint on first panel and second paint a first chart, but second has bad dimension; see image.

How i can adjust my problem?

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pratiche complessive",
            dataset, true, true, false);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(560, 370));
    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();

    PieSectionLabelGenerator gen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator(
            "{1} pratica/che");
    plot.setLabelFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 10));
    plot.setLabelLinkPaint(Color.BLACK);
    plot.setLabelLinkStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    plot.setLabelOutlineStroke(null);
    plot.setLabelPaint(Color.BLUE);
    plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);
    plot.setLabelGenerator(gen);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.orange);
    chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(this);
    this.setContentPane(chartPanel);
}

public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {

    ChartEntity entity = event.getEntity();
    String sezione = "";
    sezione = entity.toString().substring(17);
    sezione = sezione.replace(")", "");
    System.out.println(sezione);
    // PieSection: 0, 0(ARCHIVIATO)===>ARCHIVIATO V
    if (entity != null) {

        try {
            String query = query;

            String numero_pratiche = "";
            String nome_stato = "";
            String data_modifica;

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            while (rs.next()) {
                dataset
            }
            // System.out.println(entity.toString());

            JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Pratiche", "Data", "Pratiche", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true, true, false);
            ChartPanel pannello_dettaglio = new ChartPanel(lineChart);
            pannello_dettaglio.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(560,367));
            this.setContentPane(pannello_dettaglio);
             JfreeChart dettaglio = new JfreeChart("Dettaglio");
            pannello_dettaglio.setSize(560, 367);
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(dettaglio);
            dettaglio.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//first panel(piechart)
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        JfreeChart demo = new JfreeChart("Pratiche complessive");
        demo.setSize(560, 367);
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }
```

this is my first chart pie:
[image: this is my first chart pie]

This is my final result:
[image: this is my final result]

Comment: Does "under" mean front-to-back or top--to-bottom?

Comment: i would like to see one panel chart top-to-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to see one panel chart top-to-bottom.

It looks like you're replacing the entire pie chart panel with the line chart panel. Instead, add both chart panels and update the line chart's dataset in the `ChartMouseListener`. The listening line chart will update itself in response. In the example below, the listener updates the line chart's dataset to reflect which pie section was clicked. For reference, it also displays the corresponding `ChartEntity`.

[image: chart image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.ChartEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.PieSectionEntity;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36889641/230513
 */
public class PieLineTest {

    public void display() {
        final DefaultPieDataset pieData = new DefaultPieDataset();
        pieData.setValue("One", 42);
        pieData.setValue("Two", 84);
        JFreeChart pieChart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
            "Title", pieData, true, true, false);
        DefaultCategoryDataset lineData = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Title", "Domain", "Range", lineData);
        ChartPanel piePanel = new ChartPanel(pieChart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
        };
        piePanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
                updateLineData(cme);
            }

            @Override
            public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
                updateLineData(cme);
            }

            private void updateLineData(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
                ChartEntity ce = cme.getEntity();
                lineChart.setTitle(ce.getClass().getSimpleName());
                lineData.clear();
                if (ce instanceof PieSectionEntity) {
                    PieSectionEntity e = (PieSectionEntity) ce;
                    DefaultPieDataset d = (DefaultPieDataset) e.getDataset();
                    Comparable sectionKey = e.getSectionKey();
                    lineData.addValue(1, e.toString(), "Begin");
                    lineData.addValue(d.getValue(sectionKey), e.toString(), "End");
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        f.add(piePanel);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(lineChart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new PieLineTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: oht, it's fantastic!!! while if i would like to see front-to-back panel chart what i must change?

Comment: Look for examples that are [_overlaid_](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20overlaid).