# JFree to create a chart with the name not getting reflected in the output

Tags: java, awt, jfreechart

```
package awc;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import org.omg.CORBA.Environment;

import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.Status;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel; 
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset; 
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset; 
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame; 
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities; 

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;


public class awc extends ApplicationFrame implements ItemListener 
{

protected static int foreign = 0;
protected static int indian = 0;
protected static int irr = 0;
protected static int other = 0;
protected static int i_one=0,i_two=0,i_three=0,f_one=0,f_two=0,f_three=0;
public static final int flag1=0;

public static int findSentiment(String tweet) {   //API FOR NLP PROCESSING
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP("MyPropFile.properties");
    int mainSentiment = 0;
    if (tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0) {
        int longest = 0;
        Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(tweet);
        for (CoreMap sentence : annotation
                .get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            Tree tree =sentence
                    .get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
            int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
            String partText = sentence.toString();
            if (partText.length() > longest) {
                mainSentiment = sentiment;
                longest = partText.length();
            }

        }
    }
    return mainSentiment;
}



public awc(String title)
{   super(title); //PASSING CHART TITLE AS A CONSTRUCTOR TO THE SUPER CLASS

}
   public static boolean flag=false;
   public Frame mainFrame;
   public Label h1,h2,h3;
   public Panel header;
   public Panel controlPanel;
   public Label searchLabel;
   public Label statusLabel;
   public Panel endPanel;
   public Label lab;
   Checkbox stweet,asearch;
   CheckboxGroup radio;
   Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("bg.png");
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
       g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
   }
   public void initi()
   {  setLayout(null);
      setBackground(Color.orange);
      setForeground(Color.blue);
      Label h1=new Label();
      Font font = new Font("TimesNewRoman", Font.BOLD,15);
      h1.setText("WELCOME TO TWITTER DATA MINING");
      h1.setFont(font);
      h1.setForeground(Color.black);
      h1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
      h1.setBounds(740,50,320,20);
      Label h2=new Label();
      h2.setText("SELECT ANY ONE OF THE OPERATION THAT YOU WISH TO PERFORM:");
      h2.setForeground(Color.red);
      h2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
      h2.setFont(font);
      h2.setBounds(600,90,580,20);
      this.setSize(new Dimension(2500,2500));
      radio=new CheckboxGroup(); 
      stweet=new Checkbox("Search Tweet",radio, false);
      asearch=new Checkbox("Advanced search",radio, false);
      stweet.addItemListener(this);
      asearch.addItemListener(this);
      stweet.setBounds(850,130,140,15);
      asearch.setBounds(850,170,160,15);
      asearch.setFont(font);
      stweet.setFont(font);
      add(h1);
      add(h2);
      add(asearch);
      add(stweet);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   private CategoryDataset createDataset( )//CREATING CHART PARAMETERS
   {  
      final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );  
      final String population="population";
      final String india = "India";        
      final String foreig = "Foreign";
      final String irrelevant="Un-fit";
      final String neg = "Ind-Negative";        
      final String neu = "Ind-Neutral";
      final String pos="Ind-Positive";
      final String f_neg = "Foreign-Negative";        
      final String f_neu = "Foreign-Neutral";
      final String f_pos="Foreign-Positive";
      final String pop="Indian";
      final String popf="Foreign";
      dataset.addValue(  indian,population,india);        
      dataset.addValue(  foreign,population,foreig);        
      dataset.addValue(  irr,population,irrelevant);
      dataset.addValue( i_one ,pop,neg);
      dataset.addValue( i_two ,pop,neu);
      dataset.addValue( i_three ,pop,pos);
      dataset.addValue( f_one ,popf ,f_neg);
      dataset.addValue( f_two , popf,f_neu );
      dataset.addValue( f_three ,popf,f_pos);
      return dataset; 
   }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
   { 
    if(stweet.getState() == true)
         {flag=true;
         prepareGUI();
         }
     else if(asearch.getState() == true)
     {                                                }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      awc chart = new awc("Twitter data mining"); //SETTING OAUTH PARAMETERS FOR TWITTER-4J
      ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");
      cb.build();
      chart.initi();
   }

public void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new Frame("Twitter Data Mining");
      mainFrame.setSize(2500,2500);
      mainFrame.setBackground(Color.orange);
      mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
      h1 = new Label();
      h1.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
      h2 = new Label();
      h2.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
      header = new Panel();
      header.setLayout(null);
      controlPanel = new Panel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      endPanel = new Panel();
      endPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      mainFrame.add(header);
      mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
      mainFrame.add(endPanel);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      showTextFieldDemo();
   }

   public void showTextFieldDemo(){
       Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,12);
        h1.setText("WELCOME TO TWITTER DATA MINING");
        h1.setBounds(840,50,225,35);
        h1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        h1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        h1.setFont(font);
        h2.setText("1.SEARCH TWEET");
        h2.setBounds(750,90,230,55);
        h2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        h2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        searchLabel = new Label();        
        searchLabel.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        searchLabel.setText("\nENTER THE SEARCH WORD:");
        searchLabel.setBounds(700,70,80,25);
        searchLabel.setFont(font);
        searchLabel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        searchLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      final TextField userText = new TextField(15);
      Button sbutton = new Button("CLICK TO SEARCH");
      sbutton.setFont(font);
      header.add(h1);
      controlPanel.add(searchLabel);
      controlPanel.add(userText);
      controlPanel.add(sbutton);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      Button cbutton = new Button("CLICK HERE FOR GRAPHICS VIEW");
      Button close=new Button("Close");
      close.setFont(font);
      cbutton.setFont(font);

      sbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
               try {
                String data=searchTweet(twitter,userText.getText());
                System.out.println("After returned:"+data);
                statusLabel = new Label();        
                statusLabel.setLocation(400,130);
                statusLabel.setText("RESULT");
                statusLabel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                statusLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                final TextArea result=new TextArea(data,80,150);
                endPanel.add(statusLabel);
                endPanel.add(result);
                controlPanel.add(cbutton);
                controlPanel.add(close);
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }         
         }
      });
      close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
              System.exit(0);
          }
      });  

   cbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
          chartd("Comparision between Foreign twitter users");
           pack( );        
          RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(mainFrame);        
          setVisible( true );         
       }
    });  
 }

   public void chartd(String chartTitle ) //CHART INITIALISATION
   {
       JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(chartTitle,           
                 "Country",            
                 "No. of users", 
                 createDataset(),          
                 PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL,           
                 true, true, false);
       barChart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);  
       final CategoryPlot plot = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
       plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
       plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
       plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
       ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( barChart );        
              chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension( 300 , 250 ) );        
              setContentPane( chartPanel ); 
   }   
   public static String searchTweet(Twitter tw, String word) throws IOException //SEARCH OPERATION
    {
       String data = " ";
       String state="INDIA india Andhra Pradesh Arunachal Pradesh Assam Bihar Chhattisgarh Goa Gujarat Haryana Himachal Pradesh Jammu and Kashmir Jharkhand Karnataka Kerala Madhya Pradesh Maharashtra Manipur Meghalaya Mizoram Nagaland Orissa Punjab Rajasthan Sikkim TamilNadu Tripura Uttarakhand Uttar Pradesh West Bengal Tamil Nadu Tripura Andaman and Nicobar Islands Chandigarh Dadra and Nagar Haveli Daman and Diu Delhi Lakshadweep Pondicherry ";
       File fp = new File("/home/siva/Downloads/city.txt");
       Scanner scanner=new Scanner(fp);
       ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
       while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
           list.add(scanner.nextLine()); 
       }
       scanner.close();
       try { int count=1;
                System.out.println("Search in progress...");
                Query query = new Query(word);
                QueryResult result;
                do {
                    result = tw.search(query);
                    List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                    for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                        if(tweet.getPlace()!=null)
                        {System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getName() + " - "+"Place : "+tweet.getPlace()+"Location:"+tweet.getUser().getLocation());
                         if(tweet.getPlace().getCountryCode().equalsIgnoreCase("IN")||(tweet.getPlace().getCountryCode().equalsIgnoreCase("IND")))     
                          {indian+=1;

                          if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                            {i_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                          else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                            {i_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                          else
                            {i_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}

                          }
                         else                     
                          {
                             foreign+=1;

                             if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                {f_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                              else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                {f_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                              else
                                {f_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}                       

                          }
                        }
                        else
                        {   System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getName() + " - "+"Location:"+tweet.getUser().getLocation()+"\tTime:"+tweet.getUser().getUtcOffset());                      
                        if(list.contains(tweet.getUser().getLocation())&&(tweet.getUser().getLocation().length()>=0))
                            {
                             indian+=1;

                             if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                {i_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                              else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                {i_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                              else
                                {i_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}


                            }
                            else{
                           if(((tweet.getUser().getLocation().contains("India"))||(tweet.getUser().getLocation().contains(state))))
                            {
                               indian+=1;

                               if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                {i_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                              else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                {i_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                              else
                                {i_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}
                            }
                            else
                            {   if((tweet.getUser().getUtcOffset()!=19800)&&(tweet.getUser().getUtcOffset()!=-1))
                                   {
                                       foreign+=1;

                                       if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                          {f_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                                      else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                          {f_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                                      else
                                          {f_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}   

                                   }
                              else{ 
                                   if((tweet.getUser().getUtcOffset()==-1))
                                     { if((tweet.getUser().getLocation().length()==0)||(tweet.getUser().getLocation().length()==1))
                                          irr+=1;
                                        else
                                          {

                                            foreign+=1;

                                            if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                            {f_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                                          else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                            {f_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                                          else
                                            {f_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}   

                                          }
                                     }
                                  else  
                                      {
                                      if((tweet.getUser().getLocation().length()==0)||(tweet.getUser().getLocation().length()==1))
                                          {
                                             foreign+=1;

                                             if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                                {f_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                                             else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                                {f_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                                              else
                                                 {f_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}   
                                           }
                                      else{
                                        if(!(tweet.getUser().getLocation().contains("Lanka")))
                                         {
                                            indian+=1;

                                            if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                            {i_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                                          else if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                            {i_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                                          else
                                            {i_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}
                                         }
                                        else
                                         {
                                            foreign+=1;

                                            if(findSentiment(tweet.getText())==1)
                                            {f_two++;System.out.println("\n--Negative--\n");}
                                          else if(
                                                  findSentiment(tweet.getText())==2)
                                            {f_one++;System.out.println("\n--Neutral--\n");}
                                          else
                                            {f_three++;System.out.println("\n--Positive--\n");}   
                                         }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                            }
                           }
                        }

                           {FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/home/siva/Documents/file.txt",true);
                           BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(file);
                           buf.flush();
                           data+="\n\n"+count+". \nNAME:"+tweet.getUser().getName()+"\nLocation:"+tweet.getUser().getLocation()+" - "+"\nTWEET:"+tweet.getText();
                           buf.append("\nName:"+tweet.getUser().getName()+ " - "+"Location:"+tweet.getUser().getLocation()+"\nTweet:"+tweet.getText()+"\n");
                           buf.close();
                           count+=1;}
                      }//end for
                    }while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);//end do while

                }///end try
             catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
                data="\nFailed to search tweets because of rate limiting...";
             }
         System.out.println("\nIndia:"+indian+"\nForeign:"+foreign+"\nOther:"+other+"\nIrr:"+irr);
         System.out.println("ONE:"+i_one+"Neg:"+i_two+"Pos:"+i_three);
         System.out.println("ONE:"+f_one+"Neg:"+f_two+"Pos:"+f_three);

        return data;
    }   
}
```

[image]
 ***THE IMAGE SHOWS THAT THE NAME IS NOT THE SAME AS PASSED IN THE 
PROGRAM***

The image has a chart title which depicts the name of the chart. But the name of the chart that has been passed as a parameter in the code is not getting reflected in the output. 
        Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add image pls?

Comment: What image? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on the problem you describe, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36889641/230513).

Comment: @trashgod *"What image?"* There was a hanging reference to an image in the text. I included it again. Definitely agree about the MCVE. That's over 450 lines of code to show "Can't set the title!". I expect that could be done in < 50 LOC.

Answer (score 1):

After revising your example to focus on the problem, several issues arise:

- Your implementation of `chartd()` specifies `PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL`, while your screenshot is `PlotOrientation.VERTICAL`. Along with the errant title, it's clear that you're creating one chart and displaying another.
- Don't add AWT components, e.g. `Frame` and `Label`, to a Swing [top-level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) such as [`ApplicationFrame`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/ApplicationFrame.html), a subclass of `JFrame`.
- Don't construct the GUI on the [initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).
- Don't use null [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) capriciously.

The example below illustrates these points.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36929231/230513 */
public class Test {

    private static final int foreign = 1;
    private static final int indian = 2;
    private static final int irr = 3;
    private static final int other = 4;
    private static final int i_one = 1, i_two = 2, i_three = 3,
        f_one = 1, f_two = 2, f_three = 3;

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(createChart("Comparision among foreign twitter users"));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ChartPanel createChart(String chartTitle) //CHART INITIALISATION
    {
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(chartTitle,
            "Country", "No. of users", createDataset(),
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, false);
        final CategoryPlot plot = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
        BarRenderer r = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        r.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(barChart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        return chartPanel;
    }

    private CategoryDataset createDataset()//CREATING CHART PARAMETERS
    {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        final String population = "Population";
        final String india = "India";
        final String foreig = "Foreign";
        final String irrelevant = "Un-fit";
        final String neg = "Ind-Negative";
        final String neu = "Ind-Neutral";
        final String pos = "Ind-Positive";
        final String f_neg = "Foreign-Negative";
        final String f_neu = "Foreign-Neutral";
        final String f_pos = "Foreign-Positive";
        final String pop = "Indian";
        final String popf = "Foreign";
        dataset.addValue(indian, population, india);
        dataset.addValue(foreign, population, foreig);
        dataset.addValue(irr, population, irrelevant);
        dataset.addValue(i_one, pop, neg);
        dataset.addValue(i_two, pop, neu);
        dataset.addValue(i_three, pop, pos);
        dataset.addValue(f_one, popf, f_neg);
        dataset.addValue(f_two, popf, f_neu);
        dataset.addValue(f_three, popf, f_pos);
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```