# ChartPanel not registering as a component in a GUI

Tags: java, swing, components, jfreechart

I have the following output.

```
Recursive call for org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel[chartpanelBoa
Component count 0 for org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel[chartpanelBoa
```

The code i run to get this output is

```
public void enableEverything(Container c){
Component [] p = c.getComponents();
System.out.println("Component count " + c.getComponentCount() + " for " +   
                                c.toString().substring(0,40)  );
for(Component pp : p){
pp.setEnabled(true);
if(pp instanceof Container){
System.out.println("Recursive call for " + pp.toString().substring(0,40));
enableEverything((Container) pp);
}
else System.out.println("No recursive call");
}



}
```

The ChartPanel can be be seen in my JPanel, however it wont count the chartpanel. I am expecting an output of

Component count 1 for org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel[chartpanelBoa

What sits behind the scenes that counts the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the source for [`org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.java), a `ChartPanel` *is a* `JPanel`, but it contains no nested instances of `Component`. A [handful](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.java#L95) of Swing components are imported to handle a [context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284972/230513), tooltips, etc., but the enclosed [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) itself is pure [Java2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_2D).

It looks like you want to alter the chart's visual representation when it is disabled. You can still invoke [`setEnabled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled-boolean-) on the `ChartPanel` itself to leverage the `JPanel` UI delegate. You can also modify the interior of the chart as desired; this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668380/230513) dims the background using `setBackgroundPaint()` or `setBackgroundImageAlpha()`.

Comment: yes i am looking to first get a count of the chart panels and then alter the visual representation. I will set enabled() to true.

Comment: Sounds good; for comparison, you can "see a dump of the active Swing container hierarchy" as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305265/230513).